# creating angularjs + signalr service

Tags: angularjs, signalr

I am creating a generic angular service that will do native operations of signalr

```
angular.module('signalr', []).provider('signalrService', [function () {

var configuration;
this.config = function (config) {
    configuration = config;
};

this.$get = ['$log', '$timeout', '$q', '$rootScope', function ($log, $timeout, $q, $rootScope) {
    return new signalrService(configuration, $log, $timeout, $q);
  }];

}])


function signalrService(configuration, $log, $timeout, $q, $rootScope) {



if (!configuration) {
    $log.log('Invalid config');
    return;
}

var signalRhubs = $.hubConnection();


if (!signalRhubs) {
    $log.log('SignalR is not referenced.');
    return;
}

signalRhubs.logging = configuration.logging;



var warmMeUp = signalRhubs.createHubProxy('userHub');


warmMeUp.on('getOnlineUserList', function (data) {
  console.log(data)   
 })




signalRhubs.connectionSlow(function () {
    $log.warn('We are currently experiencing difficulties with the connection.')
});

signalRhubs.error(function (error) {
    $log.error('SignalR error: ' + error)
});




$(signalRhubs).bind("onDisconnect", function (e, data) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $log.warn('Signalr Connection dead.')
    }, 10000);
});


this.invoke = function (hubName, serverFunction, paramObject) {

    var def = $q.defer();


    var hubProxy = signalRhubs.createHubProxy(hubName)

        signalRhubs.start().done(function () {

            if (paramObject) {

                 hubProxy.invoke(serverFunction, paramObject).done(function (data) {

                    def.resolve(data);
                }).fail(function (error) {
                    $log.error('SignalR error: ' + error)
                    def.reject();
                });
            }
            else {
                hubProxy.invoke(serverFunction).done(function (data) {
                    def.resolve(data);
                }).fail(function (error) {
                    $log.error('SignalR error: ' + error)
                    def.reject();
                });
            }
        }).fail(function () {
            $log.error('Failed to start signalR')
            def.reject();
        });

    return def.promise;
}


this.on = function (hubName,clientSubscribeFunction) {
    var def = $q.defer();
    var hubProxy = signalRhubs.createHubProxy(hubName)
        hubProxy.on(clientSubscribeFunction, function (object) {
            def.resolve(object);
        });


    return def.promise;

  }

}
```

and here is my controller

```
app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'signalrService', function ($scope, signalrService) {


signalrService.on('userHub', 'getOnlineUserList').then(function (userList) {
    console.log(userList);
});

signalrService.invoke('userHub', 'getOnlineUsers')




}]);
```

the problem here is when i uncomment my "warmUp.on" delegate in service, both generic "on" (this.on) and "warmUp.on" is executed but when i comment "warmUp.on" the generic on(this.on) delegate is also not executed .
   Please help me with the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE :hosted in github now https://github.com/pranaydutta89/angular-signalr-service

I dn't knw how but this worked for me ,i am first now warming up one function of each hub and then my delegate works for me

```
angular.module('signalr', []).provider('signalrService', [function () {

var configuration;
this.config = function (config) {
    configuration = config;
};

this.$get = ['$log', '$timeout', '$q', '$rootScope', function ($log, $timeout, $q, $rootScope) {
    return new signalrService(configuration, $log, $timeout, $q);
  }];

}])


function signalrService(configuration, $log, $timeout, $q, $rootScope) {

if (!configuration) {
    $log.log('Invalid config');
    return;
}

var signalRhubs = $.hubConnection();


if (!signalRhubs) {
    $log.log('SignalR is not referenced.');
    return;
}

signalRhubs.logging = configuration.logging;


angular.forEach(configuration.register, function (key,value) {


    var x = signalRhubs.createHubProxy(key.hub);

    x.on(key.method, function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
})





signalRhubs.connectionSlow(function () {
    $log.warn('We are currently experiencing difficulties with the connection.')
});

signalRhubs.error(function (error) {
    $log.error('SignalR error: ' + error)
});




$(signalRhubs).bind("onDisconnect", function (e, data) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $log.warn('Signalr Connection dead.')
    }, 10000);
});


    this.invoke = function (hubName, serverFunction, paramObject) {

    var def = $q.defer();

    var hubProxy = signalRhubs.createHubProxy(hubName)

        signalRhubs.start().done(function () {

            if (paramObject) {

                 hubProxy.invoke(serverFunction, paramObject).done(function (data) {

                    def.resolve(data);
                }).fail(function (error) {
                    $log.error('SignalR error: ' + error)
                    def.reject();
                });
            }
            else {
                hubProxy.invoke(serverFunction).done(function (data) {
                    def.resolve(data);
                }).fail(function (error) {
                    $log.error('SignalR error: ' + error)
                    def.reject();
                });
            }
        }).fail(function () {
            $log.error('Failed to start signalR')
            def.reject();
        });



    return def.promise;
}


this.on = function (hubName,clientSubscribeFunction) {
    var def = $q.defer();

       var hubProxy = signalRhubs.createHubProxy(hubName)
        hubProxy.on(clientSubscribeFunction, function (object) {
            def.resolve(object);
        });

       return def.promise;

  }

}
```

@angular config

```
.config(['signalrServiceProvider', function (signalrProvider) {
 //register single function of each hub to warm him up
signalrProvider.config({
    logging: true,
    register: [{
        hub: 'warmHub',
        method : 'hello'
    }, {
        hub: 'userHub',
        method: 'method2client'
    }],

    })

 }]);
```